# Retrieve Data From Previous Page

Tags: c#, html

I have a website which stores data in a session and on the 3rd page displays the entries entered on pg1 & pg2.

But on pg2, there is a back button but when it's clicked I don't know how to re-display the entry entered as its lost.

I'm new to using session storing so I may be doing something completely wrong so please advise me if I am.

Anyway my code is:

**Pg1 HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p>pg1</p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtData1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="pg1button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="pg1button_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Pg1 code behind**

```
protected void pg1button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["pg1"] = txtData1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("/Session/pg2.aspx");
}
```

**Pg2 HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<p>pg2</p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtData2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="pg2button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="pg2button_Click" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="pg2Backbutton" runat="server" OnClick="pg2Backbutton_Click" Text="Back" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Pg2 code behind**

```
protected void pg2button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["pg2"] = txtData2.Text;
    Response.Redirect("/Session/pg3.aspx");
}

protected void pg2Backbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Session/pg1.aspx");
}
```

**Pg3 HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <h1>Session State</h1>
<p>Pg 1 data is: <%=Session["pg1"] %></p>
<p>Pg 2 data is: <%=Session["pg2"] %></p>
</div>
</form>
```

Everything is working as it should except my back button. The reason for using session is that the website doesn't use a DB as the third page will have (when I get round to it) a button which will email the details to a specified email address.

I have had to strip out some parts of the HTML due to company policy so its the bare basics given, sorry.

Comment: Would disabling the `BackButton` be sufficient?

Comment: `back button but when it's clicked I don't know how to re-display the entry entered as its lost.` What is lost and where it should be displayed ? Do you mean that 'txtData1' in page1 does not show value entered before back button was clicked ?

Comment: just store `Session["pg2"] = txtData2.Text;` in your page 2 back button handler and then re-populate page 2 if you have anything in session for `pg2` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below logic inside your pg1.cs file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (txtData1.Text == string.Empty && Session["pg1"] != null)
      {
         txtData1.Text = Session["pg1"].ToString();
      }
  }
```

--SJ

Comment: Thanks this works great but I have an issue now where if I change the value once I click the 'Back' button, when on pg3 it still retains my initial entry and not my updated entry

Comment: you need to press the submit button on pg1.aspx to save the changes on session;

Comment: you could use the above logic inside your pg2.cs to display the existing session value when you move back from pg1.aspx to pg2.aspx

Comment: I am clicking the 'Submit' button when I amend the details and it goes to my 2nd page but on the third it retains the initial entry. When you say use the code above on Pg2 also, I'm a little unsure on where to put it as Pg2 doesn't need to know the value of Pg1, it's Pg3 that does so how would I do this?

Comment: I updated my answer; hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the above but i'm now having the same issue for my drop down list, i can re-display the initial value, i can change it but when on the confirmation page it still displays the intial value and not my update value.  i have a post for this if you could help it in this case also it would be great http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723493/asp-net-my-updated-value-from-drop-down-list-doesnt-update

Comment: As you helped and resolved this issue i was wondering if you are able to help me with another similar issue I am having but for my file uploads. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962252/file-upload-field-loss-value-when-naviagting-back-to-the-page

Comment: Sorry to be a pain yet again but I have tried and tried and can not find a way to do this for my checkboxes now.  Just to let you know that I am completely new to asp, mvc and c#.  My new post for checkboxes can be found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119628/retrieve-selected-checkbox-value-from-previous-page)