# Retrieve Selected Checkbox Value From Previous Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `asp.net webform` website which stores data in a session and on the 3rd page displays the entries entered on pg1 & pg2.

On the first page the first checkboxes is pre-selected by default but if the user selects/unselects a checkbox, when the user is on the second page, there is a back button but when it's clicked I don't know how to re-show the checkboxes selected/unselected as only the default one is checked.

I'm new to using ASP and session storing so I may be doing something completely wrong. How can I resolve my situation?

My code is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">All services</div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Step02AllServices" runat="server" Checked="True" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">Site content uploading only</div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Step02ContentUploading" runat="server" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">Site content &amp; layout checking</div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Step02ContentLayoutChecking" runat="server" Enabled="False" />
     </div>
</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Step02SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["Step02AllServices"] = Step02AllServices.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentUploading"] = Step02ContentUploading.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentLayoutChecking"] = Step02ContentLayoutChecking.Checked;
     Response.Redirect("/Quotation/pg3.aspx");
}
```

I know that is needs to be in my `Page_Load` just not sure how to do it.

The below is what I have for radio buttons and test fields on another page

```
if (txtData2.Text == string.Empty && Session["pg2"] != null)
{
     txtData2.Text = Session["pg2"].ToString();

     if (Session["pg2Yes"].ToString() == "Yes")
     {
          pg2Yes.Checked = Session["pg2Yes"].Equals("Yes");
     }

     if (Session["pg2No"].ToString() == "No")
     {
          pg2No.Checked = Session["pg2No"].Equals("No");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you are on page 3 and you clicked the back button which redirects you to page 2.

On load of page 2, you need to check whether it's a new load (not postback) and if it contains the values on session. If both are true, you need to get the value from session and make the checkbox selected.

So, write the following code in Page2Load

```
//if you are loading the new page
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if(Session["Step02AllServices"] != null)
    {
        Step02AllServices.Checked = (bool) Session["Step02AllServices"];
        //similarly assign other checkbox values as they are in session already
    }
    else
    {
        //do normal assignment
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same issue, when i return to the page, the default checkbox is re-checked and the one i selected isn't

Comment: Actually your solution does almost work.  The reason why it wasn't working was due to my first checkbox being selected by default.  I'll have to find another way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

check the below simple implementation and enhance it according to your requirement and can be done using single page

aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="div1" runat="server">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="div2" runat="server" visible="false">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Button3_Click"/>
        </div>
         <div id="div3" runat="server" visible="false">
             <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="Button4_Click"/>
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs code:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            div1.Visible = false;
            div2.Visible = true;
            div3.Visible = false;
        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            div1.Visible = true;
            div2.Visible = false;
            div3.Visible = false;
        }
        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            div1.Visible = false;
            div2.Visible = false;
            div3.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = CheckBox1.Checked.ToString();
            Label2.Text = CheckBox2.Checked.ToString();
            Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
            Label4.Text = TextBox2.Text;
        }
        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            div1.Visible = false;
            div2.Visible = true;
            div3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont think this is relevent for my question.  I want a solution on how to retain the checked checkbox the user selected and i cant see this anywhere in your code snippets